# How to install openboard for 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, dependencies

I know that [openboard](http://openboard.ch/download.en.html) is officaly only released for 16.04. Is there any chance to get it working under 18.04?

This is what I tried:

```
$ sudo gdebi openboard_ubuntu_16.04_1.5.2_amd64.deb 
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree        
  Reading state information... Done
  Reading state information... Done
  This package is uninstallable
  Dependency is not satisfiable: libavformat-ffmpeg56 (>= 7:2.8.15)
```

This is my `ffmpeg` version that I have currently installed:

```
ffmpeg version n4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
```

Comment: ubutnu 20.04 users can try this : https://github.com/OpenBoard-org/OpenBoard/releases/tag/v1.6.0a2  . It worked for me . I just did `sudo dpkg -i filename` . If you run into any dependency problem, try running `sudo apt install -f` . source : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UGChC58eejI

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I managed to install it with with flathub: https://flathub.org/apps/details/ch.openboard.OpenBoard

Answer (score 1):

I managed to install it from sources on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS too), following the instructions provided at the [OpenBoard github site, "Building from source"](https://github.com/OpenBoard-org/OpenBoard/wiki/Build-from-source).

I report hereinafter the steps with some very minor modification:

1. Install the required dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git qt5-default libqt5svg5-dev libqt5webkit5-dev libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev qtscript5-dev libssl-dev libpaper-dev libmotif-dev qtmultimedia5-dev qttools5-dev
   ```
2. Create a temporary build directory, and move there to download the required code

   ```
    git clone https://github.com/OpenBoard-Org/OpenBoard.git
    git clone https://github.com/OpenBoard-Org/OpenBoard-Importer.git
    git clone https://github.com/OpenBoard-Org/OpenBoard-ThirdParty.git
   ```
3. Build the Third-Party libraries

   ```
   cd OpenBoard-ThirdParty/freetype
   qmake freetype.pro -spec linux-g++
   make

   cd ../quazip
   qmake quazip.pro -spec linux-g++
   make

   cd ../xpdf/xpdf-3.04
   ./configure --with-freetype2-library="../../freetype/lib/linux" --with-freetype2-includes="../../freetype/freetype-2.6.1/include"
   cd ..
   qmake xpdf.pro -spec linux-g++
   make
   ```
4. Build the Open-Sankoré document importer (this is suggested as optional... in my case I tried it anyway)

   ```
   cd ../OpenBoard-Importer
   qmake OpenBoardImporter.pro -spec linux-g++
   make
   ```
5. Build OpenBoard

   ```
   cd ../OpenBoard
   qmake OpenBoard.pro -spec linux-g++-64
   make
   ```

If you follow the instructions there, the final `make` will fail by showing some missing dependencies. However, by looking for the names of the corresponding missing libraries in a package manager (for example, the Synaptic package manager), it is relatively easy to find the corresponding missing development packages (that is, the packages that end with `-dev`; in my case, these were `libswscale-dev`, `libva-dev`, `libxcb-shm0-dev`, `libxcb-xfixes0-dev`, `libasound2-dev`, `libsdl2-dev`, `libsdl1.2-dev`, `libx264-dev`, `libvpx-dev`, `libvorbis-dev`, `libtheora-dev`, `libopus-dev`, `libmp3lame-dev`, `libfdk-aac-dev`, `libass-dev`, `liblzma-dev`, and `libbz2-dev`).

At the end of the successful last `make` command, the binary of OpenBoard can be found in the folder `build/linux/release/product/OpenBoard`.

Comment: -1 wasn't me, but I have retracted my flag

Comment: It worked by solving a small issue at the end. I had the following issue: src/adaptors/UBExportDocument.cpp:46:14: fatal error: quazip.h: No such file or directory
     #include "quazip.h.  I solved by following the suggestion given here: https://github.com/OpenBoard-org/OpenBoard/issues/405.

Answer (score 1):

Should you still be looking for a simple solution, look here for newer packages:
https://github.com/OpenBoard-org/OpenBoard/releases/tag/v1.6.1a-1102

They are not on the official website, but are already in production use (even though official alpha (1.6.1 or beta (1.6.0)).

Answer (score 0):

I tried again (see https://askubuntu.com/a/1313339/782572) on a clean build and the link above failed. Then I installed QT5 and openboard app appeared!

Answer (score 0):

1)install flatpak

2)flatpak search openboard

The outptut of the (2) was

ch.openboard.OpenBoard 1.6.4   stable flathub Interactive whiteboard for schools and universities

3)flatpak install flathub ch.openboard.OpenBoard

Goto "Activities" on ubuntu desktop, search for openboard & you can run it from there!