# OPENBOARD podcast: failed to start encoding

Tags: 18.04

I have installed openboard on  Ubuntu 18.04 with flathub: [How to install openboard for 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128318/how-to-install-openboard-for-18-04)

Now I have the issue that I can't use the podcast. I get the error in the bottem left "failed to start encoding". How may I fix it so that I may use the podcast?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved. See [this thread](https://github.com/OpenBoard-org/OpenBoard/issues/192)

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU.  The policy here is to avoid link only answers.  Could you summarize the contents of the thread and only add the link as a reference.  This way, your answer remains valid even if the linked document disappears.